# pdflatex fatal error, despite working perfectly 2 days ago

Tags: errors, miktex

2 days ago I was using pdflatex perfectly fine. But now it stops immediately with a fatal error.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

=============From pdflatex.log:

```
2021-04-08 14:38:44,135+0800 INFO  pdflatex - this process (12212) started by 'bash' with command line: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe tutorial10.tex
2021-04-08 14:38:44,143+0800 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex.core - Bad file descriptor
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex.core - Function: flush
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex.core - Result: 9
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: <no data>
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:613
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex - Bad file descriptor
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2021-04-08 14:38:44,180+0800 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 613
2021-04-08 14:38:44,184+0800 INFO  pdflatex - this process (12212) finishes with exit code 1
```

========== from miktex-report.txt

```
ReportDate: 2021-04-08 14:47:48
CurrentVersion: 21.3
SetupDate: 2021-01-24 15:38:00
SetupVersion: 21.1
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: ab8ebca / 2021-03-19 10:22:46
OS: Windows 10 Education, 64-bit, build 18362
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: 2021-04-08 14:38:44
LastUpdate: 2021-04-08 14:36:12
LastUpdateDb: 2021-04-08 14:38:43
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
Root1: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Root2: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserConfig: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
UserData: C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
```

Comment: this here is not the right place to report bugs in applications. As I see you also opened an issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/779, but you should perhaps tell how you call pdflatex "started by bash with a full path" is a bit curious.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report.

Comment: It looks like you're using MikTeX. Is this correct? If it is, did you maybe run a MikTeX sometime during the past two days, either by hand or by some automated process? If an update was run, did you receive any error or warning messages during or at the end of the update process?  Do you run Windows? If so, which version?